# Express Handlebars Globbing

Tags: javascript, express, gulp, handlebars.js

I'm trying to setup my express app so that it will read my all of my components as partials. My tree looks like:

```
-src/
--components/
---hero
---block
```

What I want to is for my express-handlebars app engine to look in the components directory and then search the other directories for the partials, I've tried to glob this, but this doesn't seem to work.

This is what I currently have.

```
app.engine('.hbs', handlebars({
  extname: 'hbs',
  defaultLayout: 'index',
  layoutsDir: './src/pages',
  partialsDir: './src/components/**/'
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is the answer, doesn't seem that express-handlebars allows you to glob it only excepts a string or an array. Outside of that you are able to use [glob-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-fs) which will allow you to glob all of your nested partials. which you can do before settings up the express-handlebars config.

Something like this will work.

```
const express = require('express'),
      handlebars = require('express-handlebars'),
      app = express(),
      glob = require('glob-fs')({ gitignore: true });

let server,
host,
port,
files;

files = glob.readdirSync('./src/components/**/');

app.engine('.hbs', handlebars({
 extname: 'hbs',
 defaultLayout: 'index',
 layoutsDir: './src/pages',
 partialsDir: files
}));
```

Hope this helps anyone in the future.